# Save and retrieve Shape object in android give JAVA.io.NotSerializableExeception

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am using the following code to save and load arraylist of shapes Objects in drawing. but it gives AVA.io.NotSerializableExeception. how to solve this,

```
public class OffLineCanvas extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private boolean canTakeImage;
    private OffLineCanvasThread uiThread;

    private List<List<MyShape>> dequeUndo;
    private List<List<MyShape>> dequeRedo;

    private List<MyShape> shapesList;

    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<MyShape> objectsToDraw;
    private Context context;
    private Canvas can;
    private Bitmap toDisk = null;

    public OffLineCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        objectsToDraw = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<MyShape>();
        setZOrderOnTop(false);
        dequeUndo = new ArrayList<List<MyShape>>();
        dequeRedo = new ArrayList<List<MyShape>>();

        shapesList = new ArrayList<MyShape>();
        getObject(context);
    }

    public void AddShapeOffline(MyShape shape, boolean canDraw) {
        if (canDraw) {
            objectsToDraw.add(shape);
            shapesList = Conversion(objectsToDraw);
        } else {
            shapesList = Conversion(objectsToDraw);
            shapesList.add(shape);
        }
        push(shapesList);
    }

    private List<MyShape> Conversion(CopyOnWriteArrayList<MyShape> objectsToDraw) {

        List<MyShape> tList = new ArrayList<MyShape>();

        Iterator<MyShape> iTemp = objectsToDraw.iterator();
        while (iTemp.hasNext()) {
            MyShape value = iTemp.next();
            tList.add(value);
        }
        return tList;
    }

    private void push(List<MyShape> msL) {
        if (dequeUndo != null)
            dequeUndo.add(msL);
    }

    public void pop() {
        if (dequeUndo != null && dequeUndo.size() >= 0) {
            if (dequeUndo.size() > 0) {

                if (dequeRedo.size() == 0) {
                    undo(); // undo first view
                }

                List<MyShape> temp = undo();

                objectsToDraw.clear();
                if(temp.size() > 0){
                    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
                        objectsToDraw.add(temp.get(i));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                objectsToDraw.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    private List<MyShape> undo() {
        List<MyShape> temp = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<MyShape>();
        if(dequeUndo.size()>0){
            temp = new ArrayList<MyShape>(dequeUndo.get(dequeUndo
                    .size() - 1));
            dequeRedo.add(temp);
            dequeUndo.remove(dequeUndo.size() - 1);
        }

        return temp;
    }

    public void popR() {
        if (dequeRedo != null && dequeRedo.size() > 0) {
            if (dequeRedo.size() > 0) {
                List<MyShape> temp = new ArrayList<MyShape>(
                        dequeRedo.get(dequeRedo.size() - 1));
                dequeUndo.add(temp);
                dequeRedo.remove(dequeRedo.size() - 1);

                objectsToDraw.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
                    objectsToDraw.add(temp.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void SelectShapeOffile(Point point) {

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToDraw.size(); i++) {
            if (objectsToDraw.get(i).getBorderRegion().contains((int) point.x, (int) point.y)) {
                objectsToDraw.get(i).setSelectd(true);
                ((Main) context).AddShapeToOnlineCanvas(objectsToDraw.get(i));
                objectsToDraw.remove(i);
                break;
            } else {
                ((Main) context).NoShapeSelected();
                objectsToDraw.get(i).setSelectd(false);
                Log.e("asdasdasdasdadasd", "Touch OUT");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (canvas != null) {
            synchronized (getHolder()) {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                Iterator<MyShape> drawableObject = objectsToDraw.iterator();
                while (drawableObject.hasNext()) {
                    MyShape value = drawableObject.next();
                    if (canTakeImage) {
                        try {
                            value.draw(can, value.getPaint());
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        canvas.setBitmap(toDisk);
                    } else {
                        value.draw(canvas, value.getPaint());
                    }

                }

                if (canTakeImage) {
                    try {
                        saveSignature();
                        canTakeImage = false;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Bitmap saveSignature() {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
        // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Create imageDir
        File mypath = new File(directory, "profile.png");

        try {
            toDisk.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
                    new FileOutputStream(mypath));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return toDisk;
    }

    public void stopUIThread() {
        uiThread.setRunning(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        uiThread = new OffLineCanvasThread(this);
        uiThread.setRunning(true);
        uiThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        uiThread.setRunning(false);
    }

    public void clearCanvas() {
        objectsToDraw.clear();
    }

    /****************************** save file ******************************/

    public void saveCanvas() {
        canTakeImage = true;
        toDisk = null;
        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        toDisk = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), conf);
        can = new Canvas(toDisk);
        can.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        File cacheDir = null;
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            cacheDir = new File(
                    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "MyCustomObject");
        } else {
            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        }

        if (!cacheDir.exists()) {
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
        }

        boolean result = saveObject(objectsToDraw, context);

        if (result)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Saved object", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error saving object", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

    }

    public boolean saveObject(CopyOnWriteArrayList<MyShape> obj, Context c) {
        final File suspend_f = new File(c.getCacheDir(), "test");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        boolean keep = true;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(suspend_f);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            keep = false;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (oos != null)
                    oos.close();
                if (fos != null)
                    fos.close();
                if (keep == false)
                    suspend_f.delete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return keep;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public CopyOnWriteArrayList<MyShape> getObject(Context c) {
        final File suspend_f = new File(c.getCacheDir(), "test");

        CopyOnWriteArrayList<MyShape> simpleClass = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream is = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(suspend_f);
            is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            objectsToDraw = (CopyOnWriteArrayList<MyShape>) is.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String val = e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
                if (is != null)
                    is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        return simpleClass;
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Yes i was using bitmap in Myshape class. thanks for your help Antoine Marques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means either your `MyShape` class, or some of its field doesn't implement `Serializable` (which is required to be implemented, though it contains no method (it's a *marker* interface)).